# How to send JSONObject request in retrofit?

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley, retrofit2

I was trying to send JSONObject request (POST method) using retrofit and get the  results as JSONObject, how can i achieve that.? my content type is (application/json)
Could you share some of your best methods ?

retrofit Interface class

```
public interface RequestClient {
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("TripmakersLowFareShopping")
Call<FlightResponse>pushRequest(@Body FlightRequest request);  }
```

Request Model Class

```
public class FlightRequest {

@SerializedName("AgencyID")
@Expose
private String agencyID;
@SerializedName("BranchID")
@Expose
private String branchID;
@SerializedName("OriginDestinationInformations")
@Expose
private ArrayList<OriginDestinationInformation> originDestinationInformations = null;
@SerializedName("PassengerTypeQuantities")
@Expose
private ArrayList<PassengerTypeQuantity> passengerTypeQuantities = null;
@SerializedName("Password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("PricingSourceType")
@Expose
private Integer pricingSourceType;
@SerializedName("RequestOptions")
@Expose
private Integer requestOptions;
@SerializedName("SessionId")
@Expose
private Object sessionId;
@SerializedName("SupplierParameterList")
@Expose
private ArrayList<SupplierParameterList> supplierParameterList = null;
@SerializedName("Target")
@Expose
private Integer target;
@SerializedName("TravelPreferences")
@Expose
private TravelPreferences travelPreferences;
@SerializedName("UserName")
@Expose
private String userName;

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 * 
 */

public FlightRequest() {
    super();
    this.agencyID = "20083";
    this.branchID = "10161";
    this.password = "Tj9%2f30XvS59GOBsjHuMd%2bg%3d%3d";
    this.pricingSourceType = 0;
    this.requestOptions = 0;
    this.sessionId = null;
    this.target = 0;
    this.userName = "qc@*****.com";
}

public String getAgencyID() {
    return agencyID;
}

public void setAgencyID(String agencyID) {
    this.agencyID = agencyID;
}

public String getBranchID() {
    return branchID;
}

public void setBranchID(String branchID) {
    this.branchID = branchID;
}

public List<OriginDestinationInformation> getOriginDestinationInformations() {
    return originDestinationInformations;
}

public void setOriginDestinationInformations(ArrayList<OriginDestinationInformation> originDestinationInformations) {
    this.originDestinationInformations = originDestinationInformations;
}

public List<PassengerTypeQuantity> getPassengerTypeQuantities() {
    return passengerTypeQuantities;
}

public void setPassengerTypeQuantities(ArrayList<PassengerTypeQuantity> passengerTypeQuantities) {
    this.passengerTypeQuantities = passengerTypeQuantities;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Integer getPricingSourceType() {
    return pricingSourceType;
}

public void setPricingSourceType(Integer pricingSourceType) {
    this.pricingSourceType = pricingSourceType;
}

public Integer getRequestOptions() {
    return requestOptions;
}

public void setRequestOptions(Integer requestOptions) {
    this.requestOptions = requestOptions;
}

public Object getSessionId() {
    return sessionId;
}

public void setSessionId(Object sessionId) {
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
}

public List<SupplierParameterList> getSupplierParameterList() {
    return supplierParameterList;
}

public void setSupplierParameterList(ArrayList<SupplierParameterList> supplierParameterList) {
    this.supplierParameterList = supplierParameterList;
}

public Integer getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setTarget(Integer target) {
    this.target = target;
}

public TravelPreferences getTravelPreferences() {
    return travelPreferences;
}

public void setTravelPreferences(TravelPreferences travelPreferences) {
    this.travelPreferences = travelPreferences;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

}
Response model class

```
public class FlightResponse {


private JSONObject responceData;


public JSONObject getResponceData() {
    return responceData;
}

public void setResponceData(JSONObject responceData) {
    this.responceData = responceData;
}
```

}

Retrofit declaration and functional part

```
   rqbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<OriginDestinationInformation> originlist = new ArrayList<>();
            originlist.add(new OriginDestinationInformation(null,"/Date(1503599400000)/",null,"COK","DXB"));
            ArrayList<PassengerTypeQuantity> typeQuantities = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<SupplierParameterList>supplierParameterLists = new ArrayList<SupplierParameterList>();
            supplierParameterLists.add(new SupplierParameterList(false,"EndUserIPAddress","61.0.250.97"));
            supplierParameterLists.add(new SupplierParameterList(false,"EndUserBrowserAgent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"));
            supplierParameterLists.add(new SupplierParameterList(false,null,null));
            supplierParameterLists.add(new SupplierParameterList(false,"UserData","qc@tripmakers.com,971_527564545,Fateh"));
            supplierParameterLists.add(new SupplierParameterList(false,"RequestOrigin","US-localhost"));

            typeQuantities.add(new PassengerTypeQuantity(1,1));
            TravelPreferences travelPreferences = new TravelPreferences(1,1);
            FlightRequest request = new FlightRequest();
            request.setOriginDestinationInformations(originlist);
            request.setPassengerTypeQuantities(typeQuantities);
            request.setTravelPreferences(travelPreferences);
            request.setSupplierParameterList(supplierParameterLists);

            requestCall(request);
        }
    });
}

private void requestCall(FlightRequest request) {
     OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient ;

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.125:8013/flight/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    RequestClient client = retrofit.create(RequestClient.class);

    Call<FlightResponse> requestCall = client.pushRequest(request);
    requestCall.enqueue(new Callback<FlightResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FlightResponse> call, Response<FlightResponse> response) {
            Toast.makeText(RetrofitResults.this, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FlightResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(RetrofitResults.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you search SO for similar queries ? Did you try somethiing. ? We are not here to code for you, we are here to support you if you have an issue.

Comment: Sorry sir, its my first question in stack, i have added code snippet which i have done , please correct me @MatM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [this link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) 
 for complete request/response types and how to send requset and other examples of retrofit calls.

here is an example of completely working `service request` :

1.after adding dependencies for retrofit, first create your retrofit `serviceGenerator` :

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

//main donate server
private static final String SERVICE_BASE_URL = "127.0.0.1"; //add your server ip here
private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient ;
private static ServiceGenerator instance;
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(SERVICE_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

private ServiceGenerator() {
    init();
}

public static ServiceGenerator getInstance() {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ServiceGenerator();
    }
    return instance;
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}

public static void init(){
    httpClient =new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(getSSLConfig(KarizApplication.appContext).getSocketFactory());

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(Config.HTTP_LOG_LEVEL);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
    httpClient.connectTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.readTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
    retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
}
    public static Retrofit retrofit() {
    return retrofit;
}

private static SSLContext getSSLConfig(Context context) {
    try {
        // Loading CAs from an InputStream
        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        Certificate ca;
        // I'm using Java7. If you used Java6 close it manually with finally.
        InputStream cert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.donate_apache_selfsigned);
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);

        // Creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore.
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return sslContext;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

}
```

2. after that you need to create your desired `service` and `request` / `response` classes :

   ```
   public interface UserProfileServices {

   @POST("setting/update")
   Call<SettingsResponse> saveSettings(@Body SettingsRequest settingsRequest);
     }
   ```
3. `SettingRequest` class :

   ```
   public class SettingsRequest {
   @SerializedName("id")
   @Expose
   private String userId;
   @SerializedName("settings")
   @Expose
   private String settingsData;

   public String getUserId() {
   return userId;
   }

   public void setUserId(String userId) {
   this.userId = userId;
   }

   public String getSettingsData() {
   return settingsData;
   }

   public void setSettingsData(String settingsData) {
   this.settingsData = settingsData;
   }
   }
   ```
4. `SettingResponse` class :

   ```
   public class SettingsResponse  {
   @SerializedName("settings")
   @Expose
   private JSONObject settingsData;
   public JSONObject getSettingsData() {
   return settingsData;
   }

   public void setSettingsData(JSONObject settingsData) {
   this.settingsData = settingsData;
   }
   }
   ```
5. and the usage is like bellow :

   ```
    private void sendSettingsToServer(Settings setting) {
   final SettingsRequest settingsRequest = new SettingsRequest();
   settingsRequest.setUserId(KarizApplication.getUserId());
   settingsRequest.setSettingsData(setting.getSettingsData().toString());
   userProfileServices = ServiceGenerator.getInstance().createService(UserProfileServices.class);
   Call<SettingsResponse> saveSettings = userProfileServices.saveSettings(settingsRequest);
   saveSettings.enqueue(new Callback<SettingsResponse>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<SettingsResponse> call, Response<SettingsResponse> response) {
           if (response.isSuccessful()) {
               Log.d("saveSettings", "successful");
           } else {
               if (response.code() < 500) {} 
               else {}
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<SettingsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

           }
       }
   });
   }
   ```

hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, I think I have done as the same as in the above, i added my code snippet there could you please check and correct me, in my response data getresponce data is null

Comment: i checked your code , i don't see anything wrong but have you tested it ? have you got the correct response ?

Comment: something you should have in mind is that the `onResponse` gets all the responses from server , even the ones with error that your server sends you an error response and `onFailure` gets the error like *timeout* or *server unreachable* and things like that , so you have to check in your `onResponse` for the successfull responses and the others , check my answer for that ;) @VishnuMangalasseri

Comment: I tested it but it returns null value, but  i post the same class with values in post man i got the result, in post man i added content type as application/json is there any issue with my code.?

Comment: Android Monitor shows the exact JSON object that you are sending to your server, or with break points intercept your FlightRequest before sending to server and see if it contains correct values or not , but i recommend finding it in android monitor because you can then copy and paste it in postman and see if its correct or not ;) @VishnuMangalasseri

Comment: something that i found right now in response , don't forget to put `@SerializedName("")` and `@Expose` annotations just like what you did in request class .

Comment: SerializedName is about? the same name as our class right..?

Comment: and one more thing i think you can remove `@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")` from your service call interface , even though i'm always working with Content-Type:application/json, i've never used this annotation myself

Comment: serializedName is the exact parameter name that you are sending to server or the server responds to you .

Comment: is it fixed ? @VishnuMangalasseri

Comment: Thank God....! it works perfectly , I have created separate model class for response based on the structure of response with appropriate SerializedName & Expose it works like a charm...! thank you

Comment: happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity or fragment you can implements ServiceCallBack for result onSuccess or onFail and can call a method like:

```
//service call
public void callRoadTrafficIncident(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {

        BaseRequest baseRequest = new BaseRequest(this);
        baseRequest.setServiceCallBack(this);
        baseRequest.setRequestTag(UrlFactory.SAVERTI);
        Api api = (Api) baseRequest.execute(Api.class);
        if (api != null) {
            TypedInput requestBody = new TypedByteArray(
                    "application/json", jsonObject.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            api.saveRTI(requestBody, baseRequest.requestCallback());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For Api interface you can create like:

```
public interface Api {


    @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json"})
    @POST("/saveRTI")
    public void saveRTI(@Body TypedInput jsonObject, Callback<String> callback);}
```

For baseRequest class :

```
public class BaseRequest {

    private int requestTag;
    private boolean progressShow = true;
    private ServiceCallBack serviceCallBack;
    private RestClient restClient;
    private Context context;
    private Callback<Object> callback;

    public BaseRequest(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        setProgressShow(progressShow);
    }

    public Object execute(Class classes){
        if(Utils.getConnectivityStatus(context)){
            restClient=  new RestClient(context,this);
            return restClient.execute(classes);
        }else{

            //Utils.showToast(context, "Network is not available.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Callback<String> requestCallback(){

        return restClient.callback;
    }
    public Callback<Object> getCallback() {
        return callback;
    }

    public void setCallback(Callback<Object> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return restClient;
    }

    public void setRestClient(RestClient restClient) {
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }

    public ServiceCallBack getServiceCallBack() {
        return serviceCallBack;
    }

    public void setServiceCallBack(ServiceCallBack serviceCallBack) {
        this.serviceCallBack = serviceCallBack;
    }

    public int getRequestTag() {
        return requestTag;
    }

    public void setRequestTag(int requestType) {
        this.requestTag = requestType;
    }

    public boolean isProgressShow() {
        return progressShow;
    }

    public void setProgressShow(boolean progressShow) {
        this.progressShow = progressShow;
    }

}
```

For RestClient call class:

```
public class RestClient {



    private BaseRequest baseRequest;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
    private Context context;

    public RestClient(Context context, BaseRequest _baseRequest) {
        this.baseRequest = _baseRequest;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Object execute(Class classes) {
        if (baseRequest.isProgressShow())
            showProgressDialog(context);
        return setUpRestClient(classes);
    }

    private Object setUpRestClient(Class apiClasses) {

        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(UrlFactory.BASE_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptor(context))
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient));

        builder.setConverter(new StringConverter());
        RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
        return restAdapter.create(apiClasses);
    }

    public Callback<String> callback = new Callback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void success(String o, Response response) {
            if (o != null && !o.isEmpty())
            baseRequest.getServiceCallBack().onSuccess(baseRequest.getRequestTag(), o);
            dismissProgressDialog();

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            baseRequest.getServiceCallBack().onFail(error);
            dismissProgressDialog();
        }

    };

    public void showProgressDialog(Context context) {
        try {
            if (((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void dismissProgressDialog() {
        try {
            if (pDialog != null)
                pDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    class StringConverter implements Converter {

        @Override
        public Object fromBody(TypedInput typedInput, Type type) throws ConversionException {
            String text = null;
            try {

                text = fromStream(typedInput.in());
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public TypedOutput toBody(Object o) {

            return null;
        }

        private String fromStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
                out.append(newLine);
            }
            return out.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

For Service callback interface

```
public interface ServiceCallBack
{
    public void onSuccess(int tag, String baseResponse);
    public void onFail(RetrofitError error);
}
```

For SessionRequest  Intercepter

```
public class SessionRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private Context context;

    public  SessionRequestInterceptor(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
    }
}
```